# What does "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}" in application.yml (Spring boot) mean?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I wonder what this means..

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example`

in https://spring.pleiades.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Why is the address part `${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306`?

In my docker environment, I have mysql as `services:db` and Spring as `services:spring` recognizes the mysql by `${MYSQL_HOST:db}:3306` where I don't set MYSQL_HOST explicitly.

what is this

```
${MYSQL_HOST:????}
```

Comment: It references the environment variable `$MY_HOST`, but uses the value `localhost` if `$MY_HOST` is not set.

Comment: I realized that we can use like this ..${ENV_NAME:default} thank. you